# MY SITE Users Information List

Tags: my-site, web-part, user-profile, search

I am new to SharePoint and I am making a student portal site and i put who is who section. when student want to search a name on the student portal , informations will be list on the portal.
So i want to reach my site users informations and i want to show them on web part.

1. Where can i reach that my site user list with some infos (picture,id,name,surname,department)
2. Does only  Admin see the infos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is there any specific reason for not using people search? You can actually get the required details from your user profile store. Even you introduce the new user properties.

Comment: indeed people search is the way to go.